# How to load my dataset as an example from keras?

Tags: keras

I use the code from [Keras example](http://keras.io/examples/cifar10_cnn/) There, the data is loaded as a line

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
```

How to load my images  into this example? I tried to find implementations, but everything is based on open datasets that load the same way as in the Keras example.

Comment: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

Comment: what kind of data do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create folder save with training images,and use flow_from_directory():

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
```

you can found more information here:
https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/